Character contracts shapeshifting demon
I'm struggling to remember more about this work and my Google Fu has failed me. Not certain if it's a movie or TV show.
Definitely:

Is animated
Watched it somewhere around 10-15 years ago
Protagonist has a contract with a monster
In one scene the antagonist traps them in a pit or hall full of countless small monsters saying something along the lines of "even you can't eat them all" and leaving them to die

Maybe:

Is an anime
Monster looks like a spider with the face of a woman
The monster could shapeshift or manipulate shadows
I think at some point the monster makes a comment about how "the more a soul struggles the more beautiful it becomes" in reference to the contract with the protagonist

While searching it seems super similar to Black Butler but the characters don't fit and I couldn't find a scene like that.
